# Is there a bug in the svn rev macro of hudson custom email plugin?

Tags: svn, hudson

When I try to add the svn revision value to my custom email all I get is always revision 400.  The build number is correct and other information seems correct, but the svn info is totally wrong.

Any ideas?

[Here is the help page for the email extension](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Email-ext+plugin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but:

Does your build have more than 1 SVN module?  (i.e. multiple "Repository URL" in the "Source Code Management/Subversion" section of the project)

If so, Hudson + the Subversion Plugin cannot ascertain what the revision ID is since there are multiple.

Comment: Ah, that might be it.  And of course it picks the WRONG ONE.  I use one svn repo for third party software and open source stuff and the other for our source code...  I might have to contribute to the hudson tool now to fix that.  It bothers me.  I didn't even think of that...